# How to style an individual <li> as opposed to all <li> in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am having some trouble changing the colour of an item that has been added to a cart at an e-commerce project. I can make it so that when the item is clicked, the class changes and the item get a colour. As a side effect, all accompanying items get the colour as well.

The 'Service' component

```
const Service = (props) => {

    const context = useContext(ThemeContext)

    return (
        <>
            <li className={context.cartItems.some(item => item.type === "service") ? "inCart" : ""}
                onClick={() => { context.cartItems.some(item => item) ?
                    context.removeFromCart(props) : context.addToCart(props)}} >
                {props.name}
            </li>
        </>
    )
}
```

The 'Options' component which renders the above component

```
const Options = () => {

    const context = useContext(ThemeContext)

    const serviceElements = servicesList.map(service => 
        <Service key={service.id} id={service.id} name={service.name} type={service.type} /> )

    return (
        <div className={`Options-${context.theme}`}>
            <ul>
                {serviceElements}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The add and remove from cart methods

```
function addToCart(newItem) { 
        cartItems.map(item => newItem.type === item.type && removeFromCart(item)) 
        setCartItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, newItem])
    }

    function removeFromCart(itemToRemove) { 
        setCartItems(prevItems => prevItems.filter(item => 
            `${item.id}-${item.type}` !== `${itemToRemove.id}-${itemToRemove.type}`)) 

    }
```

Scss

```
.Options-light {
  .inCart {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: When the option is clicked, can you see the class being added to the li?

Comment: Yes. If I click oneof the <li>, they all get the class 'inCart'.

Comment: Are you sure you want `context.cartItems.some` but not `context.cartItems.find`?

Comment: I've tried both and they give me the same result. The program needs to know if there's an item of a certain type in the cart -- that's what I'm trying to do there.

Comment: Looks like the logic in the `Service` component was not what you want

Comment: The logic in your `Service` component doesn't make any sense `<li className={context.cartItems.some(item => item.type === "service") ? "inCart" : ""}
                onClick={() => { context.cartItems.some(item => item) ?
                    context.removeFromCart(props) : context.addToCart(props)}} >`

Comment: And try replacing `.map` with `.forEach` instead in your `addToCart` function, `.map` doesn't make any sense in that line too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Service` component you are use `context.cartItems.some` to determine if "inCart" should be used as the `className`.  **This is the problem** because `some()` will be `true` if ***any*** items are in the cart. That means every `<li>` will either have no `className`, or all with use "inCart".

What you really want is whether the current item is in the cart so I recommend the following changes:

```
const Service = (props) => {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const inCart = context.cartItems.find(item => item.id === props.id);
  return (
    <>
      <li className={inCart ? "inCart" : ""} 
        onClick={() => { 
          inCart ? 
            context.removeFromCart(props) : 
            context.addToCart(props)
         }} > {props.name}
      </li>
    </>
  )
}
```

This will only set `<li className="inCart"` for list items that are in the cart.

Your `onClick` also uses `some()` incorrectly. The way it's written it will always be `true` and always will call `removeFromCart(props)`. I changed it to act as I expect you intended, which is to add it if the item isn't there, and remove if it is.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a couple things can change.  First of all, your `className` logic in `Service` is going to add `inCart` to all of your `li`'s because it's checking the whole context array independent of the current props.  So try:

`context.cartItems.find(item => item.id === props.id) ? "inCart" : ""`

Also can clean up your content functions:

```js
function addToCart(newItem) {
  // Looks like you were trying to do a check to make sure that the item isn't
  // already in the cart
  const alreadyInCart = cartItems.some(item => item.id === newItem.id);
  if (!alreadyInCart) {
    setCartItems(prevItems => [...prevItems, newItem]);
  }
}

function removeFromCart(itemToRemove) {
  // I assume id is unique because you use it as a key for the Service component
  setCartItems(prevItems => prevItems.filter(item => item.id !== itemToRemove.id));

}
```

I think you'd probably be better off with a `toggleCartItem` though to make things cleaner and if your later "Cart" service only needs an id, then you can clean up further.  Let me know if this works a little better:

```js
const Options = () => {

  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);

  const serviceElements = servicesList.map(service => 
    <Service
      key={service.id}
      id={service.id}
      inCart={context.cartItems.some(id => service.id === id)}
    />
  );

  return (
    <div className={`Options-${context.theme}`}>
      <ul>
        {serviceElements}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

const Service = (props) => {

  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);

  return (
    <li
      className={props.inCart ? "inCart" : ""}
      onClick={() => toggleCartItem(props.id)}
    >
      {props.name}
    </li>
  )
}

function toggleCartItem(newItemId) {
  const alreadyInCart = cartItems.some(id => id === newItemId);
  if (alreadyInCart) {
    setCartItems(prevIds => prevId.filter(id => id !== newItemId));
  } else {
    setCartItems(prevIds => [...prevIds, newItemId]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SCSS doesn't have a closing bracket? it should be:

```
.Options-light {
  .inCart {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```